# Import existing Cognito UserPool to serverless framework stack

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cognito, serverless-framework

I created a Cognito UserPool using the Amazon Console, and now I want to import it to a serverless yaml file, so it will be deployed as part of a CloudFormation stack including Lambda triggres and more.

Can I somehow import the existing UserPool CloudFormation template and paste it in the serverless yaml file? or somehow import it so it can be a resource that is part of the stack?

Thanks

Comment: I know there is one option to import it Manually from AWS Console, and then referencing it in the `serverless.yml` using this manual - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-import-existing-resources-into-a-cloudformation-stack/ . But the question is if it can be referenced from the start from the `serverless.yml` ?

Answer (score 1):

Cognito UserPools aren't, unfortunately, on the list of supported resource types for importing into CloudFormation templates.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html